# ¿Debería forzar el unboxing al usar un Iterator en una colección de Wrappers?

Tags: java, optimización

Estaba trasteando en CodeFigths y he llegado a una situación como ésta:

```
int makeArrayConsecutive2(int[] statues) {    
    Set<Integer> statueSet = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(statues));
    for (int statue : statueSet) {
        System.out.println(statue);
    }
}
```

Lógicamente, me he dado cuenta de que el compilador está haciendo un montón de Autoboxing y Unboxing, así que me han surgido la pregunta:

**¿Debería forzar el unboxing de una colección de Wrappers, o utilizar el Wrapper directamente? ¿Cuáles son las ventajas e inconvenientes de cada opción?**

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con formar el unboxing? Realmente ya lo estás haciendo en ese bucle

Comment: Exacto. Mi pregunta trata sobre si es la mejor opción hacerlo o no.

Comment: La primera pregunta de cualquier optimización es si es un código tan lento o tan usado que merezca la pena optimizar. La respuesta es hacer un profiling y comprobar lo lento y/o habitual que es su ejecución.

Comment: Extrañamente, pasando ese fragmento de código por `javac` no compila.

Comment: Sí, creo que se debe a la creación del Set a partir del arreglo. Sinceramente, sabía que no compilaba desde el principio, pero creí que el propósito de la pregunta no se empañaba por ello.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He hecho unas pruebas con el siguiente código para el unboxing:

```
public class Test {
    public static void test(Set<Integer> data) {
        for (int i: data) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }   
    }
}
```

Y al compilarlo see transforma en:

```
public static void test(java.util.Set<java.lang.Integer>);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokeinterface #2,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Set.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
       6: astore_1
       7: aload_1
       8: invokeinterface #3,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
      13: ifeq          39
      16: aload_1
      17: invokeinterface #4,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      22: checkcast     #5                  // class java/lang/Integer
      25: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
      28: istore_2
      29: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      32: iload_2
      33: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      36: goto          7
      39: return
}
```

Es decir, es algo similar a:

```
public class Test {
    public static void test(Set<Integer> data) {
        for (Integer i: data) { //Se hace un casting desde Object
            int aux=i.intValue();
            System.out.println(aux);
        }   
    }
}
```

Luego la sobrecarga no es muy grande, sobre todo en tema de memoria, ya que el valor "primitivo" ya está en el wrapper.

Ahora el caso contrario, autoboxing:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void test(Set<Integer> set,int i) {
        set.add(i);
    }
}
```

Que se transforma en:

```
public class compilerTest.Test2 {
  public compilerTest.Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void test(java.util.Set<java.lang.Integer>, int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: invokeinterface #3,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Set.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      10: pop
      11: return
}
```

Que viene a ser:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void test(Set<Integer> set,int i) {
        Integer aux=Integer.valueOf(i);
        set.add(aux);
    }
}
```

En este caso el overhead es algo mayor, creando un objeto nuevo para cada valor primitivo (e incluso esto se puede estar paliando por la *cache* que suelen crear los *wrappers*, de tal modo que un si un valor ya tiene una instancia de dicho wrapper se reaprovecha<sup>1</sup>), pero en la mayoría de los casos personalmente lo consideraría asumible.

En cualquier caso, hacer "micro-optimizaciones" es algo que sólo se debe hacer si estamos seguros de que este código es un cuello de botella en el rendimiento de nuestra aplicación: ¿Se llamará este método muy a menudo? Cuando se llama ¿cuánto tiempo está la CPU procesándolo?

<sup>1</sup> Esto es lo que hace que muchas veces el siguiente código funcione, liando a los novatos en Java:

```
Integer a=5; //Autoboxing;
//Autoboxing, se detecta que ya se creó un Integer con el mismo valor y lo reúsa
Integer b=5; 

if (a==b) { ... } // Funciona aunque no se use a.equals(b)
```

Comment: Recordad todos no alargar la conversacion. Eliminad los comentarios obsolotos y si necesitais una sala de chat para seguir hablando , avisadme :P

Answer (score 6):

Vamos por partes.

**Primero**, el código que presentas **no compila**. El problema es que no se puede inferir el tipo de dato de aquí:

```
Set<Integer> statueSet = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(statues));
```

En realidad, el tipo de dato inferido no es `Integer` sino `int[]`. Sucede que la firma del método es `Arrays#asList(Object ... varargs)`. **`int[]` es una clase**, así que al tener lo siguiente:

```
int[] statues = { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int[]> statuesList = Arrays.asList(); //compila
System.out.println(statuesList); //imprime algo como [ @ab3421 ] puesto que llama a `int[].toString()`
```

Para que tu código compile, o bien cambias el tipo de dato del parámetro de `int[]` a `Integer[]` o cambias el `Set<Integer>` a `Set<int[]>`. Recomiendo cambiar el tipo de dato del parámetro `Integer[]`.

**Segundo**, el autoboxing en tu código se ejecuta solo en una parte:

```
//aquí
for (int statue : statueSet) {
```

El for mejorado, que se incluye desde Java 6, es azúcar sintáctico (syntax sugar) para lo siguiente (excepto para los arreglos de primitivos):

```
for(Iterator<Integer> it = statueSet.iterator(); ; it.hasNext()) {
    Integer miVariable = it.next();
    //...
}
```

En este caso, como fuerzas a que la iteración se haga con un primitivo, se hará el unboxing en ese momento solamente:

```
for(Iterator<Integer> it = statueSet.iterator(); ; it.hasNext()) {
    Integer miVariable = it.next();
    int statue = miVariable.intValue();
    //usar la variable statue para el código dentro del for...
}
```

---

Ahora, ¿cuál es el costo en performance del boxing/unboxing?

Hice unas pruebas usando Java 1.8.0_65, [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) 1.19 (porque las pruebas usando `System.nanoTime()` son muy inocentes) en MacOS X Sierra, procesador 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GBs de ram, 256 MBs dedicados para la JVM. Estos son los resultados:

- Recorrer los elementos de un arreglo de 10 elementos, sin unboxing:

  0.001 ±(99.9%) 0.001 ms/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (≈ 10⁻³, 0.001, 0.001), stdev = 0.001
  CI (99.9%): [0.001, 0.001] (assumes normal distribution)
- Recorrer los elementos de un arreglo de 10 elementos, con unboxing:

  0.001 ±(99.9%) 0.001 ms/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (≈ 10⁻³, 0.001, 0.001), stdev = 0.001
  CI (99.9%): [≈ 10⁻³, 0.001] (assumes normal distribution)
- Recorrer los elementos de un arreglo de 10 000 elementos, sin unboxing:

  0.001 ±(99.9%) 0.001 ms/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (≈ 10⁻³, 0.001, 0.001), stdev = 0.001
  CI (99.9%): [≈ 10⁻³, 0.001] (assumes normal distribution)
- Recorrer los elementos de un arreglo de 10 000 elementos, con unboxing:

  0.001 ±(99.9%) 0.001 ms/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (≈ 10⁻³, 0.001, 0.001), stdev = 0.001
  CI (99.9%): [≈ 10⁻³, 0.001] (assumes normal distribution)

En resumen, tu preocupación por el consumo de cpu y tiempo de ejecución de operaciones boxing y unboxing es **irrelevante**. Esto probablemente no sea un cuello de botella.

El código del benchmark lo pueden encontrar [aquí](https://github.com/luiggi0925/benchmark-unboxing) (código algo extenso).

Comment: +1 Por la aserción de las pruebas infantiles. :-o También por el uso de  JMH. ;)